# Are functions defined within the `useEffect` hook redefined every time that hook is run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

It's the React development team's official recommendation to define a function invoked within the `useEffect` hook within the hook itself if the intent is to avoid the exhaustive-dependencies error.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html

Search for: "The recommended fix is to move that function inside of your effect. That makes it easy to see which props or state your effect uses, and to ensure they’re all declared:"
What I'm wondering is whether that function will be defined again and again every time the hook is run and whether, as a consequence of this, there could be performance issues.

Comment: It is a good question, I'm also curious about the answer. Nevertheless, I think whatever the answer, it should not be any performance issue, mainly because useEffect hooks should not be used to be triggered too often. If you are running too often useEffect, you should try using states or something else .

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I would go with **yes**: any time a `useEffect` is executed, you can imagine having a room filled with fornitures (one forniture is one variable/method defined inside the `useEffect`). Once the `useEffect` has ended, all the fornitures are removed, so, next time it is called, you need to place the fornitures back again.
Honestly, I would always defines the method outside, and then play with dependencies and `useCallback`s